# How to display strange characters in Android

Tags: java, android, utf-8, ascii

Could someone shed me light on why strange characters does not appear in Android listView?

I have a text file with this

[image]

And I got this

[image]

Here is my code

```
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    InputStream inStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.emoticons);
    InputStreamReader inputReader = null;


    if (inStream != null)
    {

        try {
            inputReader = new InputStreamReader(inStream, "UTF-8");
        }catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        int c, i=0;
        //int i=0;
        char [] cb = new char[1];
        byte [] buf = new byte[100];
        String line = "";

        int ble = -1;

        try {
            ble = inputReader.read(cb, 0, 1);
        }catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        while (ble > -1)
        {

            if(cb[0] == '\r' || cb[0] == '\n')
            {
                try{
                    line = new String(buf, 0, i, "UTF-8");
                }catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                i=0;
                list.add(line);
            }

            else
            {

                buf[i++] = (byte) cb[0];
            }

            try {
                ble = inputReader.read(cb, 0, 1);
            }catch (IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }



    String[] emoticons = list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, emoticons);
    listview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to do? This code is really hard to follow. It looks like you are reading the file character by character, but then convert each character into a byte? Why?

Comment: @Teofilo you need to just add the font to  your project done !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are trying read a file line-by-line. One way to do that is using the `BufferedReader` class:

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
InputStream inStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.emoticons);
BufferedReader inputReader = null;

if (inStream != null)
{
    try {
        inputReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inStream, "UTF-8"));
        String line;
        while ((line = inputReader.readLine()) != null) {
            list.add(line);
        }
    // handle exceptions..
    } finally {
        if (inputReader != null) inputReader.close();
    }
}

String[] emoticons = list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
```

Comment: Yay! your code works but there are some characters missing, could you figure why? http://img822.imageshack.us/img822/5056/vq74.png

Comment: The characters are missing because the font does not have glyphs for them. I don't know if/how you can install a different font.